# How to update the value of nicEdit textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, nicedit, laravel-blade

Hi I have a table contains a list of posts and two buttons in each post (delete and edit) .All fields get edited but I can not edit the nicEdit textarea but when I try to edit the first article's textarea it get edited 
here is my jquery code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     $("#myForm").submit(function() {
       $("textarea").each(function(){ 
         new nicEditors.findEditor(this.id).saveContent();
       });
     });
   });
</script>
```

this is my view :

```
         @foreach($articles as $post)

            <tr>

            <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
            <td>{{$post->published_at}}</td>
            <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit{{$post->id}}" ><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></button></p></a></td></a>
            <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete{{$post->id}}" ><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></p></td>
        <div class="modal fade" id="edit{{$post->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Edit l'article : {{$post->id}}</h4>
              </div>    
              <div class="modal-body"> 
                          {!! Form::model($post,['method' => 'PATCH','files'=> true,'id'=>'myForm','route' => ['articles.update', $post->id]])!!}

        @include('partials.postForm')

        </div>
</tr> 

    @endforeach
```

Comment: id attribute has to be unique so calling `each` on selector by id (`"#{{$post->id}}"`) has no sense. Show us your html.

Comment: I get the id of the post i want to edit {{$post->id}} its a loop through all posts

Comment: @RafałŁużyński I showed my html code can you help !

Comment: Describe your problem better, I can't get what you are up to.

Comment: @RafałŁużyński  im trying to edit a post with an nicEdit textarea but I can not edit textarea's value the only one I can edit is the first one in the first post (cuz I have a table contains post's id title ).

Comment: Are you try to edit the niceditor's content?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
   $("textarea").each(function(){ 
     $(this).val($(this).closest('tr').find('.nicEdit-main').html());
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
$('.nicEdit-main').html(/*updated content*/);
```